# с++ Свой контейнер

Tags: c++

У меня возникла проблема с реализацией своего контейнера по типу map.
Задумка была в сохранении ключей в древо, а значений в файл.

```
using pm1_t = lib::PersistentMap <int,int>;
pm1_t myMap();
//999 key , 100 value
myMap[999] = 100;
```

То есть 999 идет в авл дерево, а потом создается файл с именем 999 и в него сохраняется значение 100.

Вопрос в том, как поймать оператор приравнивания, дабы записать значение в файл.

P.S.

Например имеется у меня такой код.

```
class fixed_array
{
public:
typedef int size_type;
fixed_array(size_type size) : size_(size) 
{
    data_ = new T[size_];
}
size_type size() const { return size_; }

T& operator[](size_type index)
{
    //assert(index < size_);
    return data_[index];
}

const T& operator[](size_type index) const
{
    assert(index < size_);
    return data_[index];
}
private:
    T* data_;
    size_type size_;
};

void main()
{
    using pm1_t = fixed_array <int, int>;
    pm1_t myMap(3); 
    //хотелось как перехватить тут оператор приравнивания
    myMap[1] = 100;

}
```

Не могу понять как перехватить значение 100, и сохранить его в файл сразу.

Comment: Э, если вы реализовали самостоятельно контейнер, то вопрос о перегрузке присваивания стоять не должен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор [] должен возвращать объект специального класса (прокладку), у которой уже и будет переопределен оператор присваивания. См. например, реализацию std::vetctor.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMap;
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMapProxy
{
    PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent;
    T1 key;
    PersistentMapProxy( PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent, T1 key )
      : parent(parent) , key(key)
    {}        
    const T2& operator = ( const T2& value ) const
    { parent.assign( key, value );  return value; }
    operator const T2& () const { return parent.get( key ); }
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMap
{
    ....   
    typedef PersistentMapProxy<T1, T2> Proxy;
    Proxy operator[] ( T1 key ) { return Proxy(*this, key); }
    void assign( T1 key, const T2& value ){ .... }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Если можно, пример использования данной структуры не помешал бы.

Comment: спасибо большое, я теперь понимаю конструкцию.

Comment: У меня есть вопрос, а что если я хочу послать myMap[1] в какой нибудь метод, например inc(myMap[1]), где инк это void inc(int& a). Компилятор ругается на не стыковку типов &int  и proxy

Comment: Никак. Приведение к int& - предоставление пути для последующей модификации переменной, фактически по указателю на неё, т.е. без вызова дополнительной функции. Именно этого ты и хотел избежать.

Comment: Все понял... это была ловушка здания... myMap[2] = 20; int c = 30;modify(c);
modify(myMap[2]);myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;
assert(myMap[2] == 45);  Спасибо большое.

Comment: Конкретно в этой формулировке, все же можно:  пока modify(...) только модифицирует переменную по ссылке, но не сохраняет ссылку ( story_to_future_modify(...) ), можно вернуть из Proxy ссылку на временную переменную, а в деструкторе Proxy проанализировать не изменилась ли эта переменная. Но это очень ошибка-опасный путь, поскольку пользователь касса быстро напишет story_to_future_modify.