# Proxy класс для своего контейнера и его использование

Tags: c++

Один добрый человек в [моем прошлом вопросе о контейнерах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514115/%D1%81-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80) дал описание proxy класса для перехвата *rvalue* `mymap[100] == 200;`. То есть 999 идет в АВЛ дерево, а потом создается файл с именем `999`, и в него сохраняется значение 100.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMap;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMapProxy
{
    PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent;
    T1 key;
    PersistentMapProxy(PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent, T1 key)
      : parent(parent), key(key)
    {}

    const T2& operator = (const T2& value) const
    {
         parent.assign(key, value); 
         return value;
    }

    operator const T2& () const
    {
        return parent.get(key);
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMap
{
    // ...

    typedef PersistentMapProxy<T1, T2> Proxy;

    Proxy operator[] (T1 key)
    {
        return Proxy(*this, key);
    }

    void assign(T1 key, const T2& value){ /*...*/ }

    // ...
};
```

Proxy класс работает безукоризненно при простых операциях вроде:

```
myMap[1] = 10;
myMap[2] = 20;
int c = 30;
myMap[3] = c;
```

Но стоит мне немного усложнить присваивание, как возникает ошибка.

Представим, что у нас есть метод:

```
void modify(int& a) {а += 5;}
```

и мне нужно выполнить данное действие:

```
modify(myMap[2]);
```

то есть взять и увеличить значение в ячейке `[2]` на 5 пунктов.
При этом возникают ошибки:

> 1) (active) initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
>
> 2) C2664 'void modify(int &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const
>   lib::PersistentMapProxy' to 'int &'

Метод `modify` обязан быть использован и менять его не могу, а значит нужно что-то делать с контейнером и proxy классом.

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как решить данную проблему? И желательно дать пример решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMapProxy
{
    PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent;
    T1 key;
    T2 value;
    PersistentMapProxy(PersistentMap<T1, T2> & parent, T1 key)
      : parent(parent), key(key), value( parent.get(key) )
    {}

    const T2& operator = (const T2& value_) const
    {
        value=value_;
        parent.assign(key, value); 
        return value;
    }

    operator T2& ()
    {
        return value;
    }
    ~PersistentMapProxy()
    {
        if(value!=parent.get(key))
            parent.assign(key, value);
    }
};
```

Но этот подход настолько ошибкоопасен что на собеседовании такое лучше не показывать.

Правильный способ - исправить функцию modify, так чтобы она принимала Proxy в качестве аргумента.

Answer (score 0):

Если очень нужно обеспечить возможность вызова вида `modify(myMap[2]);`, то достаточно реализовать оператор преобразования Вашего proxy-типа к неконстантной ссылке на тип (по аналогии с имеющейся константной):

```
operator T2&()
{
    return parent.get(key); // тут должна быть соответствующая версия get
}
```